# How to create a custom messagebox with check box in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am working for a Project where i have to create a check box inside a message box.
For Example, Don't show this message again? in a checkbox. 
let me know some useful tips.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a userform and design it how you want.

Comment: Hi Andreas,Thanks for your response. Could you please show me an example? if possible

Comment: This is the first link when i googled it https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html

Comment: if your messageboxes don't need user-action you can have a look at my [non-blocking notifications](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS)

Comment: Hi Krish, Thanks for your response. I have a form and when user clicks the button, the messagebox appears. But in future, the message box shoudl appear depends on user value either they want to see the messagebox (notification) or not. It doesnt have user action. Just a notification. I will look into your solution

Comment: Anyway Thanks Andreas I will look into your solution as well

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a dirty cheap solution you could use a standard messagebox with three buttons like this:

```
ret = MsgBox("Click Yes to continue." & vbNewLine & "Click No for no more messages." & vbNewLine & "Click Cancel to cancel", vbYesNoCancel)
```

The variable ret will now hold the value what the user selected.

[image]

```
           Yes           No          Cancel
```

Comment: Currently I have exact solution but I want to have a check box nearer to "Yes" or "No" button. So that Messagebox wnt appear in the future if checkbox is checked For Example, "Don't show this message again?" like in most of the Microsoft Products

Comment: In that case you must use a userform and there is no point in "making one" for you since you can't copy a design. Userforms is design (and some coding) not only something you copy paste.

Comment: Ok Andreas Thanks for your suggestion